# R igraph color vertices

Tags: r, igraph, vertex

I'm trying to make a connectogram using code that's worked for me before but for some reason I'm having issue with the color of the vertices

```
plot(net, edge.width=sqrt(links$weight), edge.arrow.size=0, 
     edge.lty=1, arrow.mode=0, vertex.size=10,
     vertex.label=nodes$Name, vertex.label.dist=1.3, 
     vertex.label.cex=1.2, vertex.label.degree=-pi/4, 
     vertex.color=nodes$Team, layout=layout_in_circle)
```

The error I'm getting is
`Error in symbols(x = coords[, 1], y = coords[, 2], bg = vertex.color,  :  invalid color name 'Biomarkers'`

Biomarkers is one of the variables in the Teams column. I'm attaching figures that are generated when I take out the vertex.color piece, so I know the rest of it works, and when I get this error (ignore the label overlap, I'll fiddle with that later)

[image: Connectogram2]

[image: Connectogram]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Without your data, we cannot know for sure,  but it looks like nodes$Team is a character variable, strings. If you got it to work for you before,  you probably had Teams as a factor variable (which would be interpreted as integers).   You might try `nodes$Team=as.factor(nodes$Team)` before calling your plot statement.

Comment: Ah yep, needed to be a factor, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the error message that you would get if `nodes$Team` is a character variable, i.e. strings. You can get around this by making Team into a factor variable.

```
nodes$Team=as.factor(nodes$Team)
```